# How to use minitoc heading in cyrillic

Tags: koma-script, polyglossia, cyrillic, minitoc

I would like to use minitoc in my document which is in bulgarian.
When I don't use language option for minitoc package everything is fine except mini table of contents heading which is in English. When I add language option everything goes wrong and I am getting strange errors (e.g. **Undefined control sequence. ^^I\section**). I am using polyglossia package since I want to use some of the windows fonts. The example below uses KOMA script but the situation is the same with memoir.
I am using MiKTeX on Windows 7 64 bit.

Here is MWE:

```
 \documentclass{scrbook}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Cambria}
 %\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{Cambria}
 \setmainlanguage{bulgarian}
 %\usepackage{minitoc}
 \usepackage[bulgarian]{minitoc}
 \dominitoc     
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \begin{document}   
 \tableofcontents   
 \chapter{Глава 1.}
 \minitoc
 \mtcskip
 \section{Секция 1.}
 Първа.
 \section{Секция 2.}
 Втора.
 \section{Секция 3.}
 Трета.
 \section{Секция 4.}
 Четвърта.
 \section{Секция 5.}
 Пета.
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `minitoc` is not updated for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and hardcodes the keywords using commands such as `\CYRS`, `\cyrhrdsn` and so on.

You can simply convert the following code into proper Cyrillic Unicode letters

```
\def\ptctitle{%
   {\cyr\CYRS\cyrhrdsn\cyrd\cyrhrdsn\cyrr\cyrzh\cyra\cyrn\cyri\cyre}}%
\def\plftitle{{\cyr\CYRS\cyrp\cyri\cyrs\cyrhrdsn\cyrk\ %
    \cyrn\cyra\ \cyrf\cyri\cyrg\cyru\cyrr\cyri\cyrt\cyre}}%
\def\plttitle{{\cyr\CYRS\cyrp\cyri\cyrs\cyrhrdsn\cyrk\ %
    \cyrn\cyra\ \cyrt\cyra\cyrb\cyrl\cyri\cyrc\cyri\cyrt\cyre}}%
\def\mtctitle{%
   {\cyr\CYRS\cyrhrdsn\cyrd\cyrhrdsn\cyrr\cyrzh\cyra\cyrn\cyri\cyre}}%
\def\mlftitle{{\cyr\CYRS\cyrp\cyri\cyrs\cyrhrdsn\cyrk\ %
    \cyrn\cyra\ \cyrf\cyri\cyrg\cyru\cyrr\cyri\cyrt\cyre}}%
\def\mlttitle{{\cyr\CYRS\cyrp\cyri\cyrs\cyrhrdsn\cyrk\ %
    \cyrn\cyra\ \cyrt\cyra\cyrb\cyrl\cyri\cyrc\cyri\cyrt\cyre}}%
\def\stctitle{%
   {\cyr\CYRS\cyrhrdsn\cyrd\cyrhrdsn\cyrr\cyrzh\cyra\cyrn\cyri\cyre}}%
\def\slftitle{{\cyr\CYRS\cyrp\cyri\cyrs\cyrhrdsn\cyrk\ %
    \cyrn\cyra\ \cyrf\cyri\cyrg\cyru\cyrr\cyri\cyrt\cyre}}%
\def\slttitle{{\cyr\CYRS\cyrp\cyri\cyrs\cyrhrdsn\cyrk\ %
    \cyrn\cyra\ \cyrt\cyra\cyrb\cyrl\cyri\cyrc\cyri\cyrt\cyre}}%
```

and add the converted code after `\usepackage{minitoc}`. Remove `\cyr` and type in the corresponding letter; for example you'll end up with

```
\def\mtctitle{Съдържание}
```

(sorry, but it would be very tedious for me to type in the whole conversion; it should be easy with a Cyrillic keyboard).

It can also be done automagically, with a kludge using the table in `t2aenc.dfu`, but reversing the roles of the arguments.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Libertinus Serif}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{Libertinus Sans}

\setmainlanguage{bulgarian}

% kludge to convert LICR to Unicode
\begingroup
\edef\CYR{\string\CYR}%
\def\DeclareUnicodeCharacter#1#2{%
  \edef\next{\uppercase{\def\noexpand\next{\detokenize{#2}}}}\next
  \expandafter\duc\next....\duc{#1}{#2}%
}
\def\duc#1#2#3#4#5\duc#6#7{%
  \def\next{#1#2#3#4}%
  \ifx\next\CYR
    \gdef#7{\char"#6}%
  \fi
}
\input{t2aenc.dfu}
\endgroup
\let\cyr\relax

\usepackage[bulgarian]{minitoc}
\dominitoc

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Глава 1.}
\minitoc
\mtcskip

\section{Секция 1.}
Първа.

\section{Секция 2.}
Втора.

\section{Секция 3.}
Трета.

\section{Секция 4.}
Четвърта.

\section{Секция 5.}
Пета.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very boring problem I was struggling with for a long time. Now everything is fine. All your solutions works perfect.